# including images into JS object and sending through Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a JS object that collects form values and store them into arrays.

```
var myJSObject = {

    names = [],
    images = [], 
    ....
}
```

The problem I have is that my form contains images and I tried to store them in the JS object and send the whole thing through Ajax. But my images` array is always empty.

Update:

Sorry for the delay as I was busy with other projects. Here is my JS Classes:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-section">

    <div class="form-element">
     <input class="upl-img" type="file" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-element">

    </div>
    <div class="form-element">
     <input class="upl-img" type="file" />
    </div>

    </div>
```

JS:

```
var formElement = function(options){



    var defaults = {
            elemID : 0,
            elemText : " ",
            elemnOrder : 0,
            mandatory : false,
            elemType : 0,
            elemImage : null,
            formFields : []
        }


        //Some methodes

        this.construct(options);

        }


         var formSection = function(options){

        var defaults = {
            sectionID : null,
            sectionTitle : " ",
            sectionOrder : 0,
            formElements : []
        }

        //Some methodes

        this.construct(options);

        }
```

So my formSection contains an array of formElement. Each formElement could contain an image that the end user may upload.

When the end user hits submit button a function will create a new formSection object and inject in all the formElements objects. The final formSection object needs to be posted through Ajax. I tried to used a FormData object to collect files without success.

Thank you

Comment: Your question is very imprecise.  Can you include some more details about what you're trying to do, including some code showing us what you've already tried?

Comment: What form are your images in? I would recommend converting them into a Base 64 string, which should work fine, depending on the size of these images.

Comment: Do you want to upload these images from users device? Are they generated by the user on the fly? More info please.

Answer (score 0):

HTMLElement objects are complex objects, and image elements are actually files on your computer, so if it was possible it would mean UPLOADING a file to the server, which means the servers need to be specificaly involved with itsa script. im prety sure you cant send them with a simple post or get http request.
JSON is ment for passing primitive types in an object notetion style.

what you can do is use a plugin such as Uplodify, which contains a PhP script that enables uploading files to the server from you computer, by giving a URI.
but that means the php script needs to tun on the server.